# php image not showing

Tags: php, image

i have following php code which display company logo

```
     <?php
     $key=$_GET['key'];
     /// key process ///

     ////////////////////
     ?>
     <img src=images/logo.jpg" />
```

when i run this php file this show logo.jpg
but when i call this from

```
       <img src="../temp.php?key=123" width="438" height="100" />
```

it didn't show image

actually what i want to track this image.

Thanks

Comment: What does temp.php do? What do you get when you call the image directly in your browser?

Comment: That's because it is setting the img tag to read `<img src="<img src=images/logo.jpg" />" width="438" height="100" />"` which is of course, invalid html.

Comment: @Salsa no, it's not: it's setting the image tag as <img src="../temp.php?key=123"... exactly as posted - but then trying to load "<img src=images/logo.jpg" />" (which it reads from the Uri) as binary image data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use something like this :

Then `temp.php` should actually :

- send HTTP-headers for some image content-type
- and send the actual **content of the image**.

  - and not any HTML code

This is because the browser expects that the URL pointed to by the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag actually corresponds to a valid image -- and not some HTML text.

For instance, `temp.php` could contain something like this :

```
<?php
$key = $_GET['key'];
// TODO : security check on $key !!!
$file = 'images/logo-' . $key . '.jpg';
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile($file);
?>
```

As a couple of sidenotes :

- You must send the right `Content-type` HTTP header ; which means you must know if your image is a gif, jpeg, png, ...
- You must check if `$_GET['key']` is correct, to not send the content of an un-wanted file !
- There should be absolutly no white-space character before or after the `<?php ... ?>` tags : the only output must be the content of the image.

Answer (score 3):

To make this work, in your `temp.php`, you need to read and output the actual image data (preceded by `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');`.

An HTML file containing an image tag can't be used as the `src` for another image tag.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of your PHP script outputting an additional `img` tag, you would need to have it read the binary image data and output that, along with the appropriate Content-Type headers.

temp.php should be something like:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo file_get_contents($the_path_to_image);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the PHP script is returning HTML output, not an image. If you want your temp.php file to return an image that can be used within an image element, you need to use PHP-GD to create an image, import/copy the image to it, then output the image in JPEG with proper image headers.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just me or...
If the code is indeed what you have

```
 <img src=images/logo.jpg" />
```

should be

```
<img src = "images/logo.jpg">
```

It has no opening quote ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the folder path for `img` tag should not start with "/" to locate the Images or any relevant folder in which Images are there. It should be like this:  `<img src="Images/today_picks_1.jpg" alt="" >` .